# How to upload all folder to github?

Tags: github

I have created a repository on github, and run the command line `git push -u origin master`. I just find a folder over there, but I have a lot of file in my folder, but it only uploaded a folder that has no files in it.

How do I upload a folder with lots of files successfully?

I just tried the command `git add .` and `git push -u origin master`

It's not working.

Please me teach me what step I missed. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add all of the files in the folder. If you actually want to add all of it (not just some), an easy way to do that would be `git add -a` or `git add ReduxSimpleStarter/*`.

Then you need to commit them. `git commit`.

Then push.

Comment: Thanks , your answer save me .

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing, by your description (sorry, it's a bit hard to read. So correct me if I am missing some details to your problem) you're forgetting to commit the changes.

To do this you need to `git commit -m "A commit message"`. It would look something like this all together

```
git add .
git commit -m "Added a new button"
git push -u origin master
```

`commit` just tells git to save the changes you made to it's history. `add` just tells git that you want those files (in their current state) to be saved next time you `commit`.

Hopefully that solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I take another answer `git add ReduxSimpleStarter/*` work for me.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not committing your changes before pushing.
When you do this:

```
git add .
```

your files are adding to the [staging area](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository).  But you also need to commit them.  You can do this by typing this into you command line after doing the '*git add .*' command:

```
git commit -m "your commit message here"
```

Then you should be able to type '*git push -u origin master*' and your files should upload.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I take another answer git add ReduxSimpleStarter/* work for me.

Comment: Yeah, glad that worked!  I personally am a fan of using 'git add -A' rather than 'git add .' so David Heyman's answer is definitely solid.